# How to filter delta only from libdiff compared result?

Tags: python

Is there any compare method or options from `difflib` that can return lines with difference only?

So far I have tried `Differ, HtmlDiffer, difflib.unified_diff` and they always return all the lines from the comparing data even there have no difference.

Comment: I realized one of the input file is generate by windows. so now i removed the eol char, and the result look much better.. FYI unified_diff compared the eol char, but htmldiffer does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unified_diff` doesn't return all of the lines but it does show some lines either side for context.  You can use `n=0` if you don't want any context.

```
import difflib

a = ['unchanged', 'unchanged', 'unchanged', 'a', 'unchanged', 'unchanged']
b = ['unchanged', 'unchanged', 'unchanged', 'b', 'unchanged', 'unchanged']

[print(x) for x in difflib.unified_diff(a, b, n=0, lineterm='')]
```

gives

```
--- 
+++ 
@@ -4 +4 @@
-a
+b
```

from which it should be easy to extract only the last two lines, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [difflib.html.difflib.unified_diff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) to only get lines that have been changed:

> The number of context lines is set by n which defaults to three

```
from itertools import islice
from difflib import unified_diff

s1 = ['line1\n', 'line2\n', 'line3\n']
s2 = ['line1\n', 'lineX\n', 'line3\n']

print(''.join(islice(unified_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='', tofile='', n=0), 3, None)))
```

Output:

```
-line2
+lineX
```